# How to change remote build machine Visual Studio 2017

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

Not sure if this is the right place to ask..
I am developing a cross-platform project to run in a Linux environment. The machine I was connecting to before is down and so I need to change which machine I connect to. I can't seem to find a way to edit this option though. Has anybody come across this issue before?

I see where the text box is for the remote build machine information but the program won't let me write to this field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go to the top menu **Tools/Options/Cross Platform/Connection Manager**.
There you can add new machines and remove existing ones.

Sorry, the screenshot is in french. "Multiplatforme" stands for "Cross Platform" and "Gestionnaire des connexions" stands for "Connection Manager":
[image]

Further details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=vs-2017) if needed.